# iOS UIPageControl HorizontalAlignment doesn't work

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol, alignment

I've tried setting a UIPageControl frame to the full width of my screen and setting alignment in the Interface Builder to Horizontal: right but it remains as centred.

"contentVerticalAlignment" is a UIControl property and there's no mention of whether it will work for a UIPageControl in the docs. Is horizontal alignment supposed to work for a UIPageControl? If not shall I subclass it to make it work (by embedding it in a UIView and aligning it myself).

Comment: Same problem. @Bbx now you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a workaround, but you can do a homegrown size to fit like this:

```
pager.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, array.count*13, 30);
```

for a left aligned UIPageControl.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated workaround:

```
pager.frame.size.width = CGFloat(pager.numberOfPages) * 17 - 14
```

Answer (score 0):

This works very well:

```swift
pager.frame.size.width = CGFloat(pager.numberOfPages - 1) * 16 + 7
```